# REST web services method to display pdf file in browser

Tags: http, rest, pdf

I am new to the REST web services with this REST am doing some small examples, and i have a problem with producing PDF file. following method am using to produce PDF file.

```
@GET
@Produces("application/pdf")
public Response ReadPDF() {
    File file = new File("fileName.pdf");
    ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
    response.header("Content-Disposition",  "attachment; filename=restfile.pdf");
    return response.build();
}
```

this method working fine and provides pdf file to download, so on call of this REST method browser asking (save or open) option. but i wanted to display the PDF file in browser by default.

Answer (score 2):

This partly depends on whether a plugin (typically Acrobat Reader plugin) is installed. In addition, you shouldn't use `Content-Disposition: attachment` (as you're using now).

See the [Troubleshooting section of this article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Adobe_Reader).

Comment: Hi thanks for your answers and i tried after comment the line `response.header("Content-Disposition",  "attachment; filename=restfile.pdf");` but still its not displaying in browser either nor downlading. i can say there is no problem with browser setting because normally it's displaying other PDF files from internet.

Comment: I would suggest using something like Firebug or the Chrome developer's tool on a website where this works, look at the headers you get and try the same headers for your response.